# How to select opponents for TurnBaseMatches after GMS 11.0.0?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

[getSelectOpponentsIntent(...)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer.html#getSelectOpponentsIntent(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)) was a method games could call to get an opponent selection UI. The output of this was a list of selected Player IDs that you could feed into [TurnBasedMatchConfig](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatchConfig.Builder.html#addInvitedPlayers(java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) to create a match.

All overloads for this method (and its realtime multiplayer counterparts) are deprecated as of [version 11.0.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_2017_-_version_1100) of Google Play Services. The deprecation notice doesn't list a replacement and only says vague things about [G+ integration going away](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/games-authentication-adopting-google.html). Play Games switched to "Gamer IDs" [awhile back](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html) (which doesn't use G+).

It makes sense that the UI for selecting an opponent would cease showing G+ friends/circles... But how are users supposed to select Gamer ID opponents if the only UI for doing so is deprecated? Players don't know their or anyone else's Player ID (it's a long random number). Without this UI or a service that resolves Gamer IDs to Player IDs... it appears the only thing players can do is auto match random opponents and rematch already-created games.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. The only related method is `TurnBasedMultiplayer.createMatch()` which does not take any player ids. Going forward i would feel google should allow to select people from the local address book/add people by mail address and to find there corresponding player ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TurnBasedMultiplayer (the class) was deprecated.  It's replacement (TurnBasedMultiplayerClient) has a [similar method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/TurnBasedMultiplayerClient.html#getSelectOpponentsIntent(int,%20int,%20boolean)) which isn't deprecated.